# Unable to add if-block in build.xml

Tags: ant, build.xml, ant-contrib

I am unable to execute the `if` task.
My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="main">

    <property name="buildsequence.property.file.fullpath" value="D:\testant\AntExample" />

    <target name="main" depends="compile, compress" description="Main target">
        <echo>
            Building the .jar file.
        </echo>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compilation target">
        <javac srcdir="src/org" destdir="src/org" fork="yes" executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\javac"/>
    </target>

  <target name="compress" description="Compression target">
        <jar jarfile="Project.jar" basedir="src/org" includes="*.class" />

        <if>
            <available file="${buildsequence.property.file.fullpath}" />
            <then>              
                <echo message="File exist"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <echo message="File do not exist" />                
            </else>
        </if>

  </target>

</project>
```

Error:

```
Buildfile: D:\projects\Self\AntExample\build.xml
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\projects\Self\AntExample\src\org
compress:

BUILD FAILED
D:\projects\Self\AntExample\build.xml:19: Problem: failed to create task or type if
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Note: File exists at `D:\testant\AntExample`.

Comment: using an if task is not the ant way. the ant way is making a target validating and other targets depending on this target and only fire them 'if' or 'unless' a property is set to true. see https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html

Answer (score 2):

`if` is part of [`ant-contrib`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) which must be present in your classpath. Once downloaded you can put it in your Ant lib folder (*anthome*/lib), and then you need to import the tasks by adding the following line in the beginning of the buildfile:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @manouti the if task is an external extension, not part of core ANT.

The following example downloads the missing jar and calls the necessary [taskdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html) statement:

```
<project default="runif">

  <target name="init" description="Download dependencies and setup tasks">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ant-contrib.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>

    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
  </target>

  <target name="runif" depends="init" description="Example running the ant-contrib if statement">
    <if>
      <available file="file.txt" />
      <then>              
        <echo message="File exist"/>
      </then>
      <else>
        <echo message="File do not exist" />                
      </else>
    </if>
  </target>

</project>
```

The [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) extension also supports the more modern [antlib](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html) mechanism. The following example demonstrates how it uses namespaces and does not require a taskdef.

```
<project default="runif" xmlns:contrib="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

  <available classname="net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask" property="if.task.exists"/>

  <target name="init" description="Download missing dependencies" unless="if.task.exists">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ant-contrib.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>

    <fail message="ant-contrib installed run the build again"/>
  </target>

  <target name="runif" depends="init" description="Example running the ant-contrib if statement">
    <contrib:if>
      <available file="file.txt" />
      <then>              
        <echo message="File exist"/>
      </then>
      <else>
        <echo message="File do not exist" />                
      </else>
    </contrib:if>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: This code says unable to load the   [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml. It could not be found.<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="main">
 
 <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"
  classpath="D:\RTC\eclipse_rtc4\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-contrib-0.6" />
 
 <property name="buildsequence.property.file.fullpath" value="D:\testant\AntExample" />
 
    <target name="main" depends="compile, compress" description="Main target">
        <echo>
            Building the .jar file.
        </echo>
    </target>

Comment: @user3616128 I am not a fan of the ant-contrib extension. If you really want to use it, I strongly recommend that you use a more modern version. V0.6 was released 10 years ago... (2004). I suspect this might be your issue.

Comment: @user3616128 In my examples about I have provided example of how the ANT build can download and install the latest version of ant-contrib. I find it makes the build more portable.